# Need help on solving an issue with some code for my class

Tags: python

I need to create a program for my python instructor that processes a name and outputs it in the format "Last, First". The 2 different ways the user can input their name are, "first last"(no comma), or "last, first".

I've used my Python book but it does not help much when it comes to what the instructor wants from us to create.

```
 space = name.index(' ')
 first = name[0:1].upper()+name[1:space]

 comma = name.index(',')
 last = name[0:1].upper()+name[1:comma]

 print(last + ', ' + first)
```

The correct result of this program should be "Last, First" as I stated already above. I keep getting the first name entered and the output is "name, name," (name is whatever is being inputted into the input statement)
example.) user input --> 'joe bob'
          output --> 'Joe, Joe,'

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you did was `first` and `last` were assigned the same string.

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
name = 'Bob, joe'
if ',' in name:
    last, first = name.split(',')
else:
    first, last = name.split(' ')

print(last.strip().capitalize()  + ', ' + first.strip().capitalize())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Bill! This is a lot easier to understand then what I had earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
name = input("Write a name: ")

space_idx = name.index(' ')

if "," in name:
    print(name)
else:
    name = name[space_idx+1:] + ", " + name[:space_idx]
    print(name)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that both the first and last name needs to be capitalized, I should have made that more clear earlier. My final output is what it needs to be, but the first letter of each name is not capitalized. I'll try fixing this on my own but if you want to post a fix you can do so and I can check back if I can't figure it out! Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, you can use the `split()` method to convert a string into a list of words, separated by spaces.

This can be done by `words = name.split()`.

Now, assuming that you have already learned string manipulation, you can remove the comma from the end of the first name (if there is), the first word in the `words` list.

Then, simply print the list for first name and last name.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your input this really helps me! I'm completely brand new to coding and I'm a high school student taking college classes at a nearby college and Python is one of them. So the reason why I'm still having trouble with all "simple" issues is just because I'm a noob.

Comment: @KeghanPettit That's all right, a bit of commitment and effort will help you push through. I'm three years into python, and I'm already doing stuff like neural networks. I suggest codecademy for supplemental learning. Wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest way is to user rstrip and split function
getting the value in list and print it from index number

```
name = list(map(str, input().rstrip().split()))

print(name[1], name[0])
print(name[1] + ', '+ name[0])
```

Input

```
Firstname Lastname
```

OutPut

```
Lastname Firstname
lastname, Firstname
```